# Showing that a line, given it does not lie in a plane, is parallel to the plane?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

The equation of the plane is given in its parametric form. Will it suffice to show that the direction vector of the line is a linear combination of two linearly independent vectors in the plane? This would mean that the direction vector of the line lies in the plane, so it would imply that it is parallel to the plane.

Comment: where are the equations given?

Comment: If you already know that the line doesn't lie in the plane,  showing its direction vector is a combination of two l.i. vectors of the plane is certainly enough. You could also show that the normal vector of the plane is perpendicular to the line's direction vector.

Comment: It depends on the definition of "a line is parallel to a plane"...

Comment: @JeanMarie A line is parallel to a plane means they never intersect, I believe

Comment: @Wen If you take this as definition, I am afraid the issue becomes a pure tautology...

Comment: @JeanMarie I just read that what Wen said is the most common definition of a line being parallel to a plane. If so, how does this imply that the normal of the plane and the line are perpendicular?

Comment: I answer to a question by another question "What do you mean by " a line does not lie in a plane" ? Is it :"there are points of the line that do not belong to the plane" or "no point of the line belong to the plane" ?

Comment: It's the former. The latter would be false if the line intersected the plane.

Comment: Given two parallel planes $P_1,P_2$ show that any linear  combination of two vectors $(v_1,v_2)$  in $P_1$  is parallel to $P_2.$   Or their cross product is normal to both planes.

Answer (score 1):

In parametric form, the plane is formed by points $\vec{p}(u, v)$ (and $u, v \in \mathbb{R}$), where
$$\vec{p}(u, v) = \vec{p}_0 + u \, \vec{e}_u + v \, \vec{e}_v$$
and the vectors $\vec{e}_u$ and $\vec{e}_v$ are not parallel, i.e.
$$\lVert \vec{e}_u \rVert \, \lVert \vec{e}_v \rVert \ne \lvert \vec{e}_u \cdot \vec{e}_v \rvert$$
or
$$\vec{e}_u \times \vec{e}_v \ne 0$$

Let's say you have line $\vec{r}(t)$ ($t \in \mathbb{R}$),
$$\vec{r}(t) = \vec{r}_0 + t \, \vec{r}_t$$

If the question is

> Is it sufficient to show that $\vec{r}_t = \alpha \, \vec{e}_u + \beta \, \vec{e}_v$ with constants $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, when one wishes to prove that the line is parallel to the plane?

the answer is *Yes, of course*, because that is one way to define "parallel to a plane".

If the question is

> How do I prove that the line $\vec{r}(t)$ is parallel to the plane $\vec{p}(u, v)$?

then the answer is something like two easiest methods are

- Showing that $$\vec{r}_t = \alpha \, \vec{e}_u + \beta \, \vec{e}_v$$ with constants $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, as already noted
- Showing that $$\vec{r}_t \cdot \left ( \vec{e}_u \times \vec{e}_v \right ) = 0$$which is just another way to express the definition of $\vec{r}_t$ being parallel to the plane $\vec{p}(u, v)$.

  Note that because this is a [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product), we can write the same equality as
  $$\vec{e}_u \cdot \left ( \vec{e}_v \times \vec{r}_t \right ) = 0$$
  or as
  $$\vec{e}_v \cdot \left ( \vec{r}_t \times \vec{e}_u \right ) = 0$$

Personally, the latter method (using any one of the three triple product forms) is *"easiest"* for me, in particular because I don't need to introduce $\alpha$ and $\beta$ — but then again, I'm not a mathematician; I just use math as a tool for solving problems.

If we use $\vec{r}_t = ( x_t , y_t , z_t )$, $\vec{e}_u = ( x_u , y_u , z_u )$, and $\vec{e}_v = ( x_v , y_v , z_v )$, the triple product can be written as
$$x_t ( y_u z_v - y_v z_u ) + y_t ( x_v z_u - x_u z_v ) + z_t (x_u y_v - x_v y_u) = 0$$